# Proving results on derivatives of absolute value of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, proof-writing, absolute-value

I need to prove these two results:

> 1. $f(a) = 0$ and $f'(a)\neq 0$.  You can use the definition of the derivative to show the left and right derivatives of $|f|$ at $a$ are
>    unequal.
> 2. $f(a) = 0$ and $f'(a) = 0$.  You can use the definition of the derivative to show that $|f|$ is differentiable at $a$ with $|f|'(a) =0$.

**EDIT- My attempt:**
For the second one, I tried to use what was given.
By the definition of derivative of $f$ at the point $a$, we have:
$$ f'(a) =  \lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
It gives me from the given data: $$  0 = \lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{x-a}$$
Let $g(x)= \frac{f(x)}{x-a}$. It is easy to observe that: $g(x)\to 0 \Leftrightarrow |g(x)|\to 0$. So, $$  \lim\limits_{x \to a} |g(x)|= 0\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{|f(x)|}{|x-a|} = 0 $$ By definition of absolute value:
$$ |g(x)| =
\begin{cases}
\frac{|f(x)|}{x-a},  & \text{if $x \gt a$} \\[2ex]
\frac{|f(x)|}{-(x-a)}, & \text{if  $x \lt a$}
\end{cases}$$
So the right-hand derivative of $|f(x)|$ at $x=a$ is:
$$ \lim\limits_{x \to a^+} \frac{|f(x)|}{x-a} = 0 $$
and the left-hand derivative of $|f(x)|$ at $x=a$ is:
$$ \lim\limits_{x \to a^-} \frac{|f(x)|}{x-a} = 0 $$
$$ \therefore |f'(a)| = \lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{|f(x)|-|f(a)|}{(x-a)} = 0 $$

Please suggest if my solution works.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show us how far you have gotten, starting with the definition of the derivative. Your argument may need to consider positive and negative values of $f$ separately.

Comment: @EthanBolker I have added whatever I could understand, pardon if it seems too trivial.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I got late to add my approach, I am sorry about it. Kindly  have a look, and suggest if my solution is okay.

Comment: Ok, I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $$f(a)=0\;\;and\;\;f'(a)>0$$

then

$$\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(x)}{x-a}>0 \implies$$

$$\exists \eta>0 :\forall x\in(a,a+\eta) \frac{f(x)}{x-a}>0$$
$$\implies \forall x\in(a,a+\eta)\;\; f(x)>0$$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{|f(x)|}{x-a}=f'(a)$$

By the same, we will have

$$\lim_{x\to a^-}\frac{|f(x)|}{x-a}=-f'(a)$$